# Personalizar comparação entre objetos javascript

Tags: javascript, objetos

Como fazer para determinar qual valor o javascript deve usar para as operações lógicas sobre objetos?

Eu estou criando um objeto competência que precisa das seguintes funcionalidades:

- Encapsula a lógica da criação de uma competência: mês/ano no formato MM/AAAA
- Ao ser concatenado com string ele retorna o formato MM/AAAA
- Dois objetos Competência podem ser comparados

As funções str_pad() e checkdate() foram usadas da biblioteca [php.js](http://phpjs.org)

O meu problema está em comparar dois objetos. 
Uma vez que tenho duas variáveis **data1** e **data2**, eu gostaria de compará-las para saber qual é maior ou se as duas são de competências iguais, usando os operadores lógicos do javascript diretamente entre as variáveis.

**ex:** data1 > data2;  data1 == data2;

Já tentei sobrescrever o prototype.value mas não funcionou.

```js
Competencia = function(competencia){
        var date = this.dateFromCompetencia(competencia);
        
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'date', {
            value: date
        });
    };

    Competencia.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this.formatado;
    };

    Object.defineProperties(Competencia.prototype, {
        formatado: {
            get: function(){
                return this.competencia.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{4})$/,"$1/$2");
            }
        },
        competencia: {
            get: function(){
                return this.mes + this.ano;
            }
        },
        mes: {
            get: function(){
                return mes = str_pad(String(this.date.getMonth()+1), 2, '0', 'STR_PAD_LEFT');
            }
        },
        ano: {
            get: function(){
                return ano = String(this.date.getFullYear());
            }
        },
        proxima:{
            value: function(){
                var mes = str_pad(String(Number(this.mes)+1), 2, '0', 'STR_PAD_LEFT');
                var comp= mes + this.ano;
                console.log(comp);
                return new Competencia(comp);
            } 
        },
        dateFromCompetencia: {
            value: function (competencia) {
                competencia = String(competencia).replace(/\D/g, '');;
                
                var mes = competencia.substr(-6,2);
                var ano = competencia.substr(-4);

                if(!checkdate(mes, 01, ano))
                  throw new Error('Competencia incorreta');

                return new Date(ano, Number(mes)-1);
            }
        }
    });

// função str_pad e checkdate do site phpjs.org
function str_pad(e,t,n,r){var i="",s;var o=function(e,t){var n="",r;while(n.length<t){n+=e}n=n.substr(0,t);return n};e+="";n=n!==undefined?n:" ";if(r!=="STR_PAD_LEFT"&&r!=="STR_PAD_RIGHT"&&r!=="STR_PAD_BOTH"){r="STR_PAD_RIGHT"}if((s=t-e.length)>0){if(r==="STR_PAD_LEFT"){e=o(n,s)+e}else if(r==="STR_PAD_RIGHT"){e=e+o(n,s)}else if(r==="STR_PAD_BOTH"){i=o(n,Math.ceil(s/2));e=i+e+i;e=e.substr(0,t)}}return e}
function checkdate(e,t,n){return e>0&&e<13&&n>0&&n<32768&&t>0&&t<=(new Date(n,e,0)).getDate()}


try{
  
  fev14 = new Competencia('02/2014');
  
  jan15 = new Competencia('01/2015');
    
  fev2014 = new Competencia('02/2014');
  
  document.getElementById('comparacao1').innerHTML = fev14 > jan15;
  document.getElementById('comparacao2').innerHTML = fev14 > fev2014;
  
}catch(e){
  alert(e.message);
}
```

```html
Comparação <b>fev14 > jan15</b> -  
<b>Resultado</b>: <span id="comparacao1"></span>
<b>Esperado</b>: false;
<br>
<br>
Comparação <b>fev14 == fev2014</b> - 
<b>Resultado</b>: <span id="comparacao2"></span>
<b>Esperado</b>: true;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Embora em JavaScript não seja possível sobrecarregar operadores, dá para tratar como seu objeto se comportará no uso dos comparadores `>`, `>=`, `<` e `<=`. Basta você implementar o método `valueOf` do objeto. Se entendi bem seu código, ficaria assim:

```
Competencia.prototype.valueOf = function () {
    return this.date.getTime(); // retorna timestamp da data
};
```

Já quanto ao operador `==` (e também o `===`), que eu saiba não tem jeito. Dois objetos quando comparados vão sempre retornar `false`, exceto se você estiver comparando o objeto com ele próprio. Você teria que comparar os valores diretamente. Aproveitando o código acima, seria possível fazer assim:

```
fev14.valueOf() == fev2014.valueOf()
```

<sup>http://jsfiddle.net/vey5eur4/</sup>

Comment: Muito bom. Isso me deu uma idéia que eu sempre quis aplicar referente aos Objetos de Valor. Se me permite editarei sua resposta para a minha solução. Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que ajudou! Sobre a edição, depende. Se for mudar muito o que eu escrevi, talvez seja melhor postar como resposta separada (e você pode até aceitar a própria resposta se quiser).

Comment: Veja aí. O que vc acha?

Comment: Se for só acrescentar uma ou duas linhas de código, ok @PauloHenrique. Senão, melhor postar como resposta.

Comment: @PauloHenrique Agora que vi que você sugeriu uma edição. Ela acabou rejeitada por 2 usuários, pois era bem grande, alterava muito minha resposta. Recomendo mesmo postar como uma resposta à parte.

Answer (score 3):

A outra resposta do valueOf responde sobre a comparação de grandezas.

Para a comparação de igualdade, encontrei a seguinte solução:

A igualdade compara a referencia do objeto. Portanto, duas variáveis com objetos de mesmo valor não confirmarão sua igualdade se não forem referências ao mesmo objeto.

Estamos tratando de Objetos de Valor, nos quais o que importa é o valor do objeto. Eles não têm um id para identificar cada instância. Precisamos de um objeto Competência com o  valor 01/2014. Não importa qual objeto seja, desde que ele tenha esse valor, qualquer um pode ser usado.

A solução seria criar uma variável estática Array que guarda referências aos objetos instanciados dessa classe. Ao instanciar um novo objeto, verificamos se já existe um objeto dessa classe com esse valor. A instância existente deve ser usada e não criada uma nova.

Um Objeto de Valor não deve ter seu valor alterado. Podem existir várias referências, em objetos diferentes, ao mesmo objeto que se interessam somente pelo valor registrado num objeto. Se o valor for alterado por uma classe, outras que possuem referência ao mesmo Objeto de Valor podem sofrer erros devido essa alteração.

Por isso, decidi criar a propriedade instances, do objeto Competencia, que guarda as referencias às todas as instâncias criadas. Ela é uma propriedade direta do objeto Competencia, que é a função construtora de nossa classe. Por isso funciona como uma propriedade estática.

As propriedades deste objeto somente possuem getters. Uma vez instanciado, o valor desse objeto não pode ser alterado. Isso garante que todas as variáveis que fazem referencia à uma instância, vão referenciar o mesmo valor.

Esses são conceitos de Objeto de Valor definidos no livro Domain Driven Design.

```js
Competencia = function(competencia){
        
        var date = this.dateFromCompetencia(competencia);
        
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'date', {
            value: date
        });
        
  
        // Se já existe uma instância com o valor solicitado
        // Ela é retornada e não uma nova instância.
  
        if(Competencia.instances[this]){
            return Competencia.instances[this];  
        }
        else
            Competencia.instances[this] = this;  

    };
    
    Competencia.prototype.toString = function () {
        return this.formatado;
    };
    
    // valueOf garante a comparação de grandeza. 
    // Se maior ou menor
    Competencia.prototype.valueOf = function(){
        return Number(this.ano + this.mes);
    },
    
    // VARIÁRVEL ESTÁTICA
    // guarda uma referencia às instâncias criadas desta classe.
    Competencia.instances = [];
    
    Object.defineProperties(Competencia.prototype, {
        formatado: {
            get: function(){
                return this.competencia.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{4})$/,"$1/$2");
            }
        },
        
        competencia: {
            get: function(){
                return this.mes + this.ano;
            }
        },
        
        mes: {
            get: function(){
                return mes = str_pad(String(this.date.getMonth()+1), 2, '0', 'STR_PAD_LEFT');
            }
        },
        
        ano: {
            get: function(){
                return ano = String(this.date.getFullYear());
            }
        },
        
        proxima:{
            value: function(){
                var mes = str_pad(String(Number(this.mes)+1), 2, '0', 'STR_PAD_LEFT');
                var comp= mes + this.ano;
                console.log(comp);
                return new Competencia(comp);
            } 
        },
          
        dateFromCompetencia: {
            value: function (competencia) {
                competencia = retirarCaracteres(competencia);
                competencia = str_pad(competencia, 6, '0', 'STR_PAD_LEFT');
                
                var mes = competencia.substr(-6,2);
                var ano = competencia.substr(-4);

                if(!checkdate(mes, 01, ano))
                    throw new Error('Competencia incorreta');

                return new Date(ano, Number(mes)-1);
            }
        }
    }); // Fim defineProperties
    
    
// função str_pad e checkdate do site phpjs.org
function str_pad(e,t,n,r){var i="",s;var o=function(e,t){var n="",r;while(n.length<t){n+=e}n=n.substr(0,t);return n};e+="";n=n!==undefined?n:" ";if(r!=="STR_PAD_LEFT"&&r!=="STR_PAD_RIGHT"&&r!=="STR_PAD_BOTH"){r="STR_PAD_RIGHT"}if((s=t-e.length)>0){if(r==="STR_PAD_LEFT"){e=o(n,s)+e}else if(r==="STR_PAD_RIGHT"){e=e+o(n,s)}else if(r==="STR_PAD_BOTH"){i=o(n,Math.ceil(s/2));e=i+e+i;e=e.substr(0,t)}}return e}
function checkdate(e,t,n){return e>0&&e<13&&n>0&&n<32768&&t>0&&t<=(new Date(n,e,0)).getDate()}
function retirarCaracteres(e){return String(e).replace(/\D/g,"")}


try{
  
  fev14 = new Competencia('02/2014');
  
  jan15 = new Competencia('01/2015');
    
  fev2014 = new Competencia('02/2014');
  
  document.getElementById('comparacao1').innerHTML = fev14 > jan15;
  document.getElementById('comparacao2').innerHTML = fev14 == fev2014;
  
}catch(e){
  alert(e.message);
}
```

```html
Comparação fev14 > jan15. Resultado: <span id="comparacao1"></span>
<br><br>
Comparação fev14 == fev2014. Resultado: <span id="comparacao2"></span>
```

Comment: Legal! Agora que entendi melhor seu objetivo, recomendo ainda colocar `configurable` e `enumerable` como `false` para a propriedade `date` (ver https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: Eu não fiz isso porque o default é false. Mas é melhor para garantir, mesmo.

Comment: Ops, verdade. Não precisa nem garantir, vai ser `false` mesmo (assim como o writable, que é o mais importante no seu caso)